# Selenium Script to create multiple records for Dynamics CRM 365 Account Entity

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver, dynamics-crm-365

I have developed a Selenium script for Creating Multiple Records in Dynamics CRM 365 using Excel Sheet for Account entity but when i run the script the CRM System Automatically creates a blank record initially. Please find below screenshot and code for the same. (noofaccountstocreate is a variable which is used to store the integer value)

```
             int q;
        for (q = 0; q <= noofaccountstocreate; q++)
        {
            chrome.FindElement(By.Id("account|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.account.NewRecord")).Click();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            chrome.SwitchTo().Frame(chrome.FindElement(By.Id("contentIFrame1")));
            //Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Actions ikl_act3 = new Actions(chrome);

            ikl_act3.MoveToElement(chrome.FindElement(By.Id("name_d"))).SendKeys("Test " + q);

            //ikl_act3.Click();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            ikl_act3.Perform();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            ikl_act3.Release();
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            chrome.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='savefooter_statuscontrol']")).Click();

            Thread.Sleep(10000);
            chrome.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            chrome.FindElement(By.Id("Tabnav_accts-main")).Click();

            Thread.Sleep(2000);}
```

[Please see image here (Selenium Multiple Addition Error)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QSAE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft have a Selenium adapter for Dynamics 365 [here on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/EasyRepro). Try creating your account records through its API instead. Your code would look something like:

```
using (var xrmBrowser = new XrmBrowser(TestSettings.Options))
{
    xrmBrowser.LoginPage.Login(_xrmUri, _username, _password);
    xrmBrowser.GuidedHelp.CloseGuidedHelp();

    xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(500);
    xrmBrowser.Navigation.OpenSubArea("Sales", "Accounts");

    xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(2000);
    xrmBrowser.Grid.SwitchView("Active Accounts");

    xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(1000);
    xrmBrowser.CommandBar.ClickCommand("New");

    xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(4000);
    xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue("name", "Test API Account");
    xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue("telephone1", "555-555-5555");
    xrmBrowser.Entity.SetValue("websiteurl", "https://easyrepro.crm.dynamics.com");

    xrmBrowser.CommandBar.ClickCommand("Save & Close");
    xrmBrowser.ThinkTime(2000);
}
```

It's hard to diagnose your issue without debugging.